# How to shrink a react function code with firebase set/update operations

Tags: javascript, react.js, firebase

I have a function which does firebase set and update operations, but it looks messy. I want to shrink it but also make sure that it works the same. Any ideas?

```
  const handleUserSelect = async (user: Users) => {
    if (!currentUser) return;

    const combinedId =
      currentUser.uid > user.uid
        ? currentUser.uid + user.uid
        : user.uid + currentUser.uid;

    const currentUserChatsRef = doc(db, "userChats", currentUser.uid);
    const userChatsRef = doc(db, "userChats", user.uid);
    const chatsRef = doc(db, "chats", combinedId);

    const currentUserChats = await getDoc(currentUserChatsRef);
    const userChats = await getDoc(userChatsRef);
    const chats = await getDoc(chatsRef);

    if (!currentUserChats.exists()) {
      await setDoc(currentUserChatsRef, { chats: [] });
    }
    if (!userChats.exists()) {
      await setDoc(userChatsRef, { chats: [] });
    }
    if (!chats.exists()) {
      await setDoc(chatsRef, { messages: [] });
    }

    updateDoc(currentUserChatsRef, {
      chats: arrayUnion({
        uid: user.uid,
        name: user.name,
        avatar: user.avatar ? user.avatar : "",
      }),
    });
    updateDoc(userChatsRef, {
      chats: arrayUnion({
        uid: currentUser.uid,
        name: currentUser.displayName,
        avatar: currentUser.photoUrl ? currentUser.photoUrl : "",
      }),
    });
  };
```